# Adding javadoc in existing library

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc, lwjgl

I it possible to adding java comment of pre compile library jar file? I am currently experimenting with lwgjl but it lacks of documenting opengl function. I would like to adding comments on functions and properties of the library along the way i encounter new method or property.

Now i have to open both opengl and lwgjl API for referencing the methods and properties and have to look everytime it. it will be convenaince to make it compact in one place (in IDE)

Comment: If you document the source of a library you might consider pushing the comments you make back to the developers to help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the sourcecode and javadoc like this:

1. right click on your libraray
2. edit
3. select proper tab (source or javadoc)
4. add **`sourcecode`** and / or **`javadoc`**

If you want to add comments by your own, you have to extract the sourcecode and add this folder.